# How to add Vagrant box manualy

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I just updated (clean) my OS, How can I restore all of my old vagrant box If I have backup of my home folder.

Old OS: ubuntu 14.04
New OS: ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All boxes are stored under the `~/.vagrant.d` folder so if you copy the folder from the old OS, vagrant should be able to recognized them and use them for your VMs

Then you can verify that your box are available by running `vagrant box list`

Note: better to install vagrant on the new OS before copying the files.

Comment: So if I download a box manually using my download manager then I put in `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`, will it work ? Internet bandwidth is huge issue for me.

Comment: no; once you download a `.box` file from internet, you would need to register in vagrant by running `vagrant box add <boxname> <location of downloaded box file`, vagrant manages a few files under `~/.vagrant.d` folder about your installed box